# Is there a way to select rows based on data row as criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Is there a way for me to do this using a query or a stored procedure?

Example Table:

```
ID         TYPE    TIMESTAMP      QTY
P12345.1   A       2015-10-22     90
P12345.2   A       2015-10-22     0
P12001.1   A       2015-10-22     87
P12345.3   A       2015-10-23     92
P19000.1   B       2015-10-23     75
```

I want to only select the rows provided that they have the same prefix in the ID (characters prior to period (.)), and they have the same type and same timestamp.

In the example above, 3 rows have the same prefix: P12345.1, P12345.2 and P12345.3. However, only P12345.1 and P12345.2 have the same timestamp so I will be selecting the row of P12345.1 and not P12345.2.

This should be the resulting table:

```
ID         TYPE    TIMESTAMP      QTY
P12345.1   A       2015-10-22     90
P12001.1   A       2015-10-22     87
P12345.3   A       2015-10-23     92
P19000.1   B       2015-10-23     75
```

I'm really having a hard time solving this and I need to accomplish this using a query or a stored procedure. Thank you in advance. Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: So you mean, if same Pnnnnn prefix and same date, pick the row with lowest suffix?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @jarlh same prefix, same date and same type, yes. Pick the row with lowest suffix.

Comment: @brenners1302 MS SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ID, TYPE, TIMESTAMP, QTY
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where LEFT(t2.id, 6) = LEFT(t1.id, 6)
                    and t2.TIMESTAMP= t1.TIMESTAMP
                    and t2.id < t1.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT ID
      ,TYPE
      ,TIMESTAMP
      ,QTY
FROM   PrefixTable t1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT 1
           FROM   PrefixTable t2
           WHERE  SUBSTRING(t2.id ,1 ,6) = SUBSTRING(t1.id ,1 ,6)
                  AND t2.TIMESTAMP = t1.TIMESTAMP
                  AND t2.id < t1.id
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select dt.*
  from dataTable dt
 where right(dt.id,1) = (select min(right(dt2.id,1)) from dataTable dt2
                          where left(dt.id,6) = left(dt2.id,6)
                            and dt.timestamp = dt2.timestamp)
```